# What do these lines of code do? (Sports Simulation)

Tags: python, object, methods, parameters, arguments

We're doing an activity in my Computer Science class, and I'm having trouble understanding what a few lines of code mean.

Here is the initial code (for any background info that you may need).

```
class SportsMatch(object):
     def __init__(self, teamA="Team A", teamB="TeamB"):
          self.teamA = teamA
          self.scoreA = 0
          self.teamAScorePoints = 1

          self.teamB = teamB
          self.scoreB = 0
          self.teamBScorePoints = 1

     def setScorePoints(self, teamAScorePoints=1, teamBScorePoints=1):
          self.teamAScorePoints = teamAScorePoints
          self.teamBScorePoints = teamBScorePoints

     def whoWins(self):
          if (self.scoreA < self.scoreB):
               print(self.teamB+" win the game!")
          elif (self.scoreA > self.scoreB):
               print(self.teamA+" win the game!")
          else:
               print("Tie score")

     def teamAScores(self):
          self.scoreA = self.scoreA + self.teamAScorePoints

     def teamBScores(self):
          self.scoreB = self.scoreB + self.teamBScorePoints
```

Then, we're supposed to consider the following code and figure out what each line of code does:

```
s = SportsMatch("Chargers", "Raiders")
s.setScorePoints(1, 2)
s.teamAScores()
s.teamBScores()
s.teamAScores()
s.teamBScores()
s.whoWins()
```

I have a sort of general understanding, but my teacher wants us to be more specific.  I also understand that the second line is called with the parameters of 1 and 2, but I'm not sure how those numbers play into the rest of the code.  If anyone could help explain these last several lines of code to me, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it a sports *stimulation* or *simulation*? :P

Answer (score 3):

Setting initial variables:

```
self.teamX = teamX        # setting name
self.scoreX = 0           # initial score
self.teamAXcorePoints = 1 # score increment
```

These two are the score increments:

```
self.teamAScorePoints = 1
self.teamBScorePoints = 1
```

Used here to increment each team's score:

```
def teamAScores(self):
    self.scoreA = self.scoreA + self.teamAScorePoints
def teamBScores(self):
    self.scoreB = self.scoreB + self.teamBScorePoints
```

Now the flow:

```
s = SportsMatch("Chargers", "Raiders") # defining the match
s.setScorePoints(1, 2)                 # setting initial score increments
s.teamAScores()                        # team A scores 1 point
s.teamBScores()                        # team B scores 2 points
s.teamAScores()                        # team A scores another 1 point
s.teamBScores()                        # team B scores another 2 points
s.whoWins()                            # prints winner
```

Comment: Wouldn't `s.setScorePoints()` set the *increments* which would then impact every time they score? In other words, it doesn't set the initial score, it would set the amount that will be added every time that team scores.

Comment: Bob is right the `setScorePoints` sets the increment not the initial score.

Comment: My bad guys. Sorry. Updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot seeing it side by side.  Thank you for your help. (:

Answer (score 2):

A general description of the code:

```
s = SportsMatch("Chargers", "Raiders")
```

This line of code calls the `__init__` method from the `SportsMatch` class and passes the method "Chargers" and "Raiders". These are then saved as the names of the sports teams.

```
s.setScorePoints(1, 2)
```

This line calls the `setScorePoints` method from the class and passes it `1` and `2`. These values are saved as the amount that each teams scores will be incremented upon scoring.

```
s.teamAScores()
s.teamBScores()
s.teamAScores()
s.teamBScores()
```

These lines call the `teamAScores` and `teamBScores` methods. These methods increment the scores of a team depending on which method is called.

```
s.whoWins()
```

This calls the `whoWins` method of the class, which compare the teams scores and prints the winning team.

The winning team would be team B also known as `Raiders`. Team B would have a score of `4` and team A would have a score of `2`.